# Installing Ubuntu by usb

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I had a problem with installing Ubuntu's  latest version on my Windows. I tried to use a USB stick put Universal-Usb-Installer in it, I chose the file and where do I want to install but the "create" icon doesn't appear. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to install Ubuntu from a USB (bootable USB), I suggest that you create bootable USB using `dd` command in a Linux machine. An example below.

```
sudo dd if=/home/username/Downloads/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=16M
```

In the above command, `if` accepts the location of the `.iso` file (input) and `of` accepts the USB you've connected (output). You can check the information about the USB connected to the computer by providing the following code.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Today (June 2017) Ubuntu's official recommendations can be found at the following links,

- [How to create a bootable USB stick on **Ubuntu**](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) - Startup Disk Creator
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on **Windows**](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) - Rufus
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on **macOS**](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos) - Unetbootin

I can add the following links to useful tools and methods,

- on Linux (Ubuntu as well as other linux distros) - [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), cloning, wiping, restoring (to a standard storage device)
- on Windows - [Win32DiskImager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb), a cloning tool
- in order to make a *persistent live* drive - [mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent), for Ubuntu and Debian

See also the following general link and links from it for more details,

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 0):

That is a good way to resolve issue you are facing which Atish shared.
you can use unetbootin too for the same. 
http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/